# C# Issue With Scene Transition On Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

EDIT:
Would redoing the build with the scenes change anything if the same numbers are still there? In this case, I deleted two scenes, rebuilt it with the changes, and both scenes had the same build index. I think I had same issue even before rebuilding the scenes.

I've been working on a top down RPG style game where you can change scenes by interacting with a door. Two different objects have two different scripts, but load the exact same scene.

My first C# script is here to load one scene:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public KeyCode changeSceneKey;
    bool collide;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        collide = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        collide = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (collide = true && Input.GetKeyDown(changeSceneKey))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(3);
            player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
            DontDestroyOnLoad(player);
        }
    }
}
```

My second C# script is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class HouseChangeScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public GameObject player;
    public KeyCode changeSceneKey;
    bool collide;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        collide = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        collide = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (collide = true && Input.GetKeyDown(changeSceneKey))
        {
            
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
            player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
            DontDestroyOnLoad(player);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the codes to work properly and load the different scenes when interacted with, but they both load scene 2 (which is what is supposed to be loaded in the HouseSceneChange script), where the SceneChange script is supposed to load scene 3.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the OnColliderEnter function, you must put a **condition** to check what object it collided with, otherwise this function will be called upon the first encounter with any type of object and your code will not work properly.

You can write your code like this:

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
 {
     if(other.CompareTag("door_1"))
         collide = true;
 }
```

Comment: I tried that with the CompareTag, just now, but it still loads scene 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (collide == true && Input.GetKeyDown(changeSceneKey))
```

instead

```
if (collide = true && Input.GetKeyDown(changeSceneKey))
```

in both scripts

Comment: Just tried using the == in both scripts, the scene won't transition at all now

Comment: When adding a conditional to load scene 2, it loads the scene I want (ie. if I set a game manager boolean to true, it loads the store scene (scene 3)

Answer (score 0):

I see someone else suggested changing:

```
if (collide = true && Input.GetKeyDown(changeSceneKey))
```

to:

```
if (collide == true && Input.GetKeyDown(changeSceneKey))
```

Which is certainly correct.

You responded with "Just tried using the == in both scripts, the scene won't transition at all now"

If `collide == true`  prevents you from being able to load the scenes at all, then the issue must lie with this boolean. `==` actually evaluates the boolean instead of setting it like `=` does, so you should never use `=` inside an `if` statement.

This would explain why scene 2 is loaded in both scenarios. Because if you aren't checking if `collide` is true (which is not what you are doing in the code like you may think you are!) then you are running both the `LoadScene(2)` and `LoadScene(3)` methods when only the `sceneChangeKey` is pressed. `LoadScene(2)` prevails probably because it is being called last, thus loading scene 3 then 2 right afterwards.

So the you should make the aforementioned change, as well as checking if the collision trigger is working properly. You should:

- Check if there is a collider on the same object this script is on.
- Check if that collider's `isTrigger` is set to `true`.
- Check if your `collide` bool is being set properly.

Now, I have to preach this in all caps. DEBUG YOUR CODE!
Use Unity's `Debug.Log(string)` method to see if your code is doing what you think it is. Use the Unity debug mode to see hidden variables and confirm they are behaving like you expect.

If you used these tools, then you probably wouldn't even be asking this question!

Lastly, I think this may be a good excercise for you to practice what is arguably one of the most important concepts of OOP: polymorphism. This will solve this problem where you've essentially written the exact same script twice, then chacnged 1 value. This is, in the very least, super inefficient. Imagine having 20 different scene transition areas and handling them this way.

Comment: I resolved the problem by making a separate object and adding the code for the scene transitions to the object itself. Thanks for the tip, though!